# All links on Devise sign-in page redirect back to sign-in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on replacing an existing authentication system in my app with Devise, and I'm running into some trouble.

I have these four links beneath the login form:

- Sign up (uses `Devise::RegistrationsController`)
- Forgot your password? (uses `Users::PasswordsController`)
- Didn't receive confirmation instructions? (uses `Devise::ConfirmationsController`)
- Didn't receive unlock instructions? (uses `Devise::UnlocksController`)

All four of these links redirect back to the sign-in page, and I haven't been able to figure out why. I see in the server logs that these links are hitting the respective controllers, but it's not even rendering the intended page — it simply redirects back to the sign-in page.

Any idea why this might be happening?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the code for these links (in `app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb`):

```
<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
  <%= link_to "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?", new_confirmation_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.lockable? && resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) && controller_name != 'unlocks' %>
  <%= link_to "Didn't receive unlock instructions?", new_unlock_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Can you show us the link code? Are you using the correct path handlers?

Comment: @RichPeck Updated; code is above.

Comment: before action somewhere that checks current_user (or equivalent) exists, and redirects if not? maybe in your ApplicationController

Comment: @Doon I have `before_action`s for `:current_user` and `:ensure_user_signed_in`. Tried commenting them out individually and together, but it's still not working.

Comment: Check your rails log - I'm guessing it could be that you you used `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your application without adding `unless: :devise_controller?` this causes the devise controllers to redirect to the sign in page since the routes which should be open now require authentication.

Comment: Your looking for a line in the logs that says something like `filter chain halted :authentication_required`